# Scala implicit conversion of a generic argument

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have some code similar to the following, where I have a function that takes a List[TypeA], and I want to be able to call it with a List[TypeB], where I have an implicit conversion from TypeA to TypeB.

I have some sample code which works when I call the method with the List inline, but doesn't work if the list is assigned to a variable first.

Here's some code that works:

```
class Person(val name: String)
implicit def stringToPerson(str: String) : Person = new Person(str)

def printAll(list: List[Person]) {
  list.foreach(person => println("Person: " + person.name))
}

def callIt = {
  printAll(List("1","2","3"))
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work if callIt looks like this:

```
def callIt = {
  val list = List("1","2","3")
  printAll(list)
}
```

I get the error that it expects a List[Person] but I'm giving a List[String]

In my actual code, I have the list already defined somewhere else, so it doesn't end up working. What can I do to make it use the implicit conversion from String to Person, and why does it work in the first case but not the second?

Side note: it also works if I specify the type of list and have it do the conversion then:

```
val list: List[Person] = List("1","2","3")
```

But again, that's not what I want.

Do I really need to provide an implicit conversion from List[String] to List[Person]?

Comment: you should define the method printAll as: def printAll[T <% Person](ls: List[T]) = {}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your initial code works is because in `printAll(List("1","2","3"))` the **compiler uses type inference to know that Person is needed *before* it constructs the List**. That line tells the compiler it needs a `List[Person]` which then forces the call to `List()` to be returning a `List[Person]` which forces the parameters of that call to be Person which then forces the use of an implicit conversion from String to Person. Unfortunately the statement `val list = List("1","2","3")` says nothing about needing to be of type `List[Person]`